# focal mechanism(beach balls) for many Earthquakes

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

Is there a good way to automatically generate focal mechanism (beach balls) for a shapefile with about 30.000 earthquakes and store them ideally in the attribute table.

It would be the best if I could use ArcGIS or QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are some solution with ArcGIS as in [ArcObjects VB Code for drawing 2D Earthquake Focal Mechanisms in ArcMap](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/19586) (but I don't use ArcGIS)

I don't know if there is a solution with QGIS, but you can use:

**Python**

1) There is a special Python library [ObsPy](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki) (Python framework for processing seismological data) and there are examples of what you want with [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and the [Matplotlib Basemap Toolkit](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/) ([20. Basemap Plot with Beachballs](http://docs.obspy.org/trunk/tutorial/code_snippets/basemap_plot_with_beachballs.html) or [Interactive Computing with IPython for GeoScientists](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mhearne-usgs/ipythondemo/blob/master/IPythonDemo.ipynb))

[image]

2) with Google Earth as in [Easily create .kml file to plot focal mechanisms in Google Earth](http://www.geophysique.be/2012/11/13/easily-create-kml-file-to-plot-beachball-in-google-earth/)

[image]

**or R** with the package ([Seismic Focal Mechanisms in R](http://www.unc.edu/~leesj/FETCH/GRAB/Vignettes/focalmec.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Arcpy script tool can help. It draw [2D focal mechanism beach balls as Arcgis feature](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1nuR2Zc1).

See http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_16436b7230102wci7.html for detail.

[image]

Comment: The link http://pan.baidu.com/s/1nuR2Zc1 is broken

Comment: Thank you. We have a new link now:http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=380b8f93cd684dbea56083218a3b2f43

Answer (score 0):

For such a task in QGIS I would use a heatmap. Menu Raster > Heatmap.

[image]

Picture above: 2315 earthquakes from 1950 to present.

Check this tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_heatmaps.html

Comment: thanks for your quick response but I really need to display or at least have the pictures of the focal mechanism( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_mechanism )

Comment: I have not seen this anywhere in QGIS.