# Plot beachball (focal mechanism) for earthquake in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography, geology

I'm drawing earthquakes on the map using QGIS and I need to plot focal mechanism by beach balls.   I don't want to use svg because it need to transform new locations on the map.

Is there a plugin or tool that I can use for earthquake problems like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "beach ball" in this context?

Comment: @bugmenot123 It's an academia geological term aka focal mechanisms  for what amounts to a symbol http://earthquake-report.com/2014/05/17/understanding-the-mystery-of-earthquake-beach-balls/

Comment: yes . its kind of graphical solution of fault mechanism . you can see it at answers .

Comment: If you can solve my problem here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315393/visualizing-3d-focal-mechanism-beach-ball-in-qgis Then we can plot 3d focal mechanisms in qgis2threejs.
I've grappled about this problem for nights, but I can't find a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through this same problem a while back and was not able to find a solution with QGIS.  The question is asked here on SE [focal mechanism(beach balls) for many Earthquakes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134132/focal-mechanismbeach-balls-for-many-earthquakes), at the time I opted to do it with [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/supplements/meca/pspolar.html) my code is long gone but a quick search nets a few examples of what the data structure and command should look like two examples: http://eqinfo.ucsd.edu/~rnewman/howtos/gmt/tips.php
http://geophysics.eas.gatech.edu/people/anewman/classes/Intro_GMT/adv_gmt.html

From the SE post I linked to the google KML looks to be the path of least resistance, you might be able to import the KML you generate into QGIS.  As @Joseph has pointed out it seems that a custom solution is out there now, but I do not believe there is a supported plugin for it yet.

Comment: ok  . tanks . all Excellent .

Answer (score 6):

Apparently it is possible:

[image: Beachballs]

A [Friedrich Prinz](http://www.digital-geography.com/short-announcement-qgis-3-0-is-on-its-way/#comment-3192863358) mentioned in a recent [Digital Geography post](http://www.digital-geography.com/short-announcement-qgis-3-0-is-on-its-way/) about how he wrote some code to create the beachballs. Although he mentioned he might do some more work on the coding, you could try asking him directly if he could share some of the code.

Comment: Shouldn the beach balls be drawn with two dots indicating the P (Pressure) and T (Tension) axis?...

Comment: @hyprfrcb - You could ask that as a comment on the website :)